# why i can't loed an image into pygame/python3.8

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I,m following a person on youtube called "tech with Tim" and in the third lesson and when I download the images the in the video  but when I run the program I always get an error "No such file or directory", I'm actually suffering with this problem in every program hers is my code:

```
    import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 50
y = 400
width = 64
height = 64
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
vel = 5
left = False
right = False
walkCount = False


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()


# main game loop "essential"
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:
        x += vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkCount = 0
    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            right = False
            left = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    redrawGameWindow
```

pygame.quit()

note: this tutorial in 2018 and my files is in the desktop

Answer (score 0):

Is your .py file on the desktop too? Try explicitly specifying the path to your desktop from the root of the filesystem. Like, `C:\Users\RANIA_NEW\Desktop\file.jpeg`.